# Scheme - printing to screen - Normal eval

Tags: scheme

Why in the next code, nothing is displayed when we work on **Normal eval** (lazy one).

```
;;; [Number, Number -> Number]
(define (printing-sub x y)
   (display x)
   (- x y))

;;; [Number, Number -> Number] 
(define (f a b)
   (if (< a 0)
 a
       (f b (printing-sub b a))))
(f 0 0)
```

I'll exmplain: In the first iteration, we will got `(f 0 (printing-sub 0 0))`, in the 2nd: `(f (prining-sub 0 0) (prining sub (printing sub 0 0) 0).` Now, in the 3rd, we have to calculate `(printing-sub 0 0)` because we want to know `(if (<a 0)`. In this iteration 0 will print out.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "Normal eval (lazy one)"?  Are you using Racket with `#lang lazy`?

Comment: @Eli Barzilay: I mean Normal order: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Normal_order

Comment: I know what "Normal Order" means, but it's unclear what you're trying to *actually* do.  Are you using some existing implementation of a lazy evaluator, or did you implement your own, or maybe you're not using anything and just guess what it should do?

Comment: Are you sure about that? when I try to execute this code in both racket and lazy racket, I get infinite 0's.

Answer (score 0):

I too don't know what you mean by "normal eval", but I don't understand why you would expect anything but 0 to be printed out with that code. In fact it'll cause an infinite loop, printing out endless zeroes.

Note that `(printing-sub 0 0)` will always just display 0 and return 0, because `(- 0 0)` is 0. So in the first iteration you get `(f 0 (printing-sub 0 0))` which reduces back to `(f 0 0)` which causes the infinite loop.

In other words, the `if` always evaluates to `#f` because `a` will never become anything other than 0.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what happened in normal eval (knows as Normal order - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Normal_order). (printing-sub 0 0) will calculate only in the 3rd Iteration. I also think that we will enter to an infinite loop, printing out endless zeroes. But I saw in official's solution that nothing will print out to the screen.